# How to export Safari bookmarks using the command in Terminal?

Tags: terminal, safari, bookmarks

I want to make backups in Safari once a week. Tell me how to use the terminal commands to export bookmarks? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
plutil -convert xml1 -o ~/Desktop/SafariBookmarks.xml ~/Library/Safari/Bookmarks.plist
```

I saw it on https://www.dropboxwiki.com/tips-and-tricks/export-safari-bookmarks-to-html-for-osx